# Databricks - How to remove files , directories based on regular expression

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I had a lot of files in databricks and wanted to clean them. Some of the files having a prefix such as "tweets1*.
How could I delete the files using a prefix something like linux pattern. I applied the following command, and it didnt work.

```
dbutils.fs.rm("/tweets1*",recurse=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can go with the classic bash.
Inside your cell type:

```
%sh
rm -rf path/to/your/folder/tweets1*
```

When I have to perform some complex operation which I already know how to do with bash I use it directly inside the cell.

Comment: it doesnt seem working, can you check once . this is in databricks

Comment: file is still present